# Excel VBA - Routine that finds on one sheet and paste on another moving destination cells down

Tags: excel, vba

Really appreciated any help on this!

I have 3 columns on  11 excel sheets that need to be copied to a unique destination sheet.

The eleven sheets refer to months, and I need to find a row referring to that month on the new worbook in order to paste, moving cells down, and then search for the next month and do the same, until all 11 months are copied.

What I have:

Sub PopulateFileTOupload()

' variables

```
Dim strFileToSave As String

Dim wbSource As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet

Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

Dim rngToCopy1 As Range, rngToCopy2 As Range, rngToCopy3 As Range
Dim dt As String, wbNam As String, wbDir As String

Dim FoundCell As Range, FirstAddr As String, fnd As String, i As Long
```

' ================ SOURCE ================

```
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MLOURENC\Documents\0041_PRORATA_ANNUAL_CONTRACTS_UPLOAD.xls")
Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("Month1")

' ================ COPY & PASTE ================

' source range1

Set rngToCopy1 = wsSource.Range("E1", wsSource.Range("E1").End(xlDown))
Set rngToCopy2 = wsSource.Range("N1", wsSource.Range("N1").End(xlDown))
Set rngToCopy3 = wsSource.Range("P1", wsSource.Range("P1").End(xlDown))

Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MLOURENC\Desktop\UP_FRONT S&D\0041_PT\2.Anual-Template\0041_PRORATA ANNUAL CONTRACTS_UPLOAD_TEMPLATE.xls")


' Paste range1


' DON 't know....



' ================ SAVE ================
wbNam = "0041_PRORATA_ANNUAL_CONTRACTS_UPLOAD_READY_"
dt = Format(CStr(Now), "dd_mm_yyyy_hh_mm")
wbTarget.SaveAs Filename:=wbNam & dt
' ================ CLOSE ================'
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wbTarget.Close
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

End Sub

Comment: `wbSource.wsSource.Range("F1:F4").Copy` to copy and 
    `wbDestination.wsDestination.Range("A1").Insert Shift:=xlDown` to paste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to layout a bit more information about your destination book, in order to point out what you can use to identify the row to copy your data to, however...

Lets say the data in your destination workbook is formatted something like this, all in one sheet if my understanding of your question is right:

```
January
    Data
    Data
    Data
    Data
February
    Data
    Data
    Data
    Data
ETC ETC
    Data
    Data
    Data
    Data
```

**The basic steps would be:**

Identify the row number where you want to add data

```
Dim monthRow As Long
monthRow = wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("A:A").Find("January:", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
```

Check number of rows in your original data

```
Dim janRows As Long
janRows = rngToCopy1.rows.count
```

Insert that many free rows in your target book

```
wbTarget.Sheets(1).Rows(monthRow + 1 & ":" & monthRow + janRows).EntireRow.Insert
```

Transfer data across

```
wbTarget.Sheets(1).Range("B" & monthRow + 1 & ":B" & monthRow + janRows) = rngToCopy1
```

There are various ways to do this (more than one way to skin a cat), but this would be easiest i think.

I hope this helps, if not i`ll be happy to assist further.

Comment: Hi DarXyde, thank you so much! Looks I'm heading in the right direction. It is placing the cursor in the correct row, but not pasting data. This is now what I have:

Comment: Set rngToCopy1 = wsSource.Range("E1", wsSource.Range("E1").End(xlDown))
Set wbTarget = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\MLOURENC\Desktop\UP_FRONT S&D\0041_PT\2.Anual-Template\0041_PRORATA ANNUAL CONTRACTS_UPLOAD_TEMPLATE.xls")    
monthRow = wbTarget.Sheets("UAN upload").Range("J:J").Find("*1*MONTH*ANNUAL*", LookIn:=xlValues).Row
month1Rows = rngToCopy1.Rows.Count
wbTarget.Sheets("UAN upload").Rows(monthRow + 7 & ":" & monthRow + month1Rows + 7).EntireRow.Insert
wbTarget.Sheets("UAN upload").Range("E" & monthRow + 7 & ":E" & monthRow + month1Rows + 7) = rngToCopy1

Comment: Try adding `.value` to the `rngToCopy1` (ie: `rngToCopy1.value`). Also, you might need to play with the range to be inserted, i think it does insert 1 to much... `wbTarget.Sheets("UAN upload").Rows(monthRow + 7 & ":" & monthRow + month1Rows + 6).EntireRow.Insert` and 
`wbTarget.Sheets("UAN upload").Range("E" & monthRow + 7 & ":E" & monthRow + month1Rows + 6) = rngToCopy1.value`

Comment: Hi DarXyde, I got it now!

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious help :)